# Está retornando os dados inferiores á 2000, mas preciso saber em que posições esse dados estão. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var veiculos = [valores informados pelo usuário]

var teste = veiculos.filter(carro => carro <= 2000)

res.innerHTML += `${teste}, </br>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wellyngton,

Como você quer retornar o índice, talvez utilizar do filter não seja a melhor opção, ainda que seja possível.

Veja esses exemplos, utilizando o reduce e também um for mais tradicional, ambos resultando em um array contendo os índices que você deseja filtrar:

```js
let veiculos = [2001,2000,1999,3000,4000,1000,7000,8000,9999,100,500,300,800];

//Reduce
let indicesReduce = veiculos.reduce( (acumulador,carro, indice) => {
  if (carro <= 2000) {
    acumulador.push(indice);
  }
  return acumulador;
}, [] );

console.log("Reduce:", indicesReduce);

//For
let indicesFor = [];

for (const [indice,carro] of veiculos.entries()) {
  if(carro <= 2000) {
    indicesFor.push(indice);
  }
}

console.log("For:", indicesFor);
```

Referências:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: O uso do For funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar um segundo parâmetro na função que é passada como parâmetro no `filter` para pegar o índice. Exemplo:

```js
const veiculos = [9999, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000];
const indexes = [];
var teste = veiculos.filter((carro, index) => {
  if (carro <= 2000) {
    indexes.push(index);
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
});

console.log(teste, indexes);
```

Comment: Acho que o **filter** aí ficou meio fora de uso não? Pq faz o filter, mas, faz um **if** em seguida.

Comment: @LeAndrade acho que não ficou de fora, porque? basicamente ele executa um filtro em cima de um array retornando o um novo array, ou seja, passamos um predicate para o `filter` e neste predicate há um filtro com o `if`. Você vê uma outra solução? de repente não percebi algo.